# Rotating/Resizing a Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I am looking for some guidance. I would like to properly rotate and resize a view inside my scrollview. I attached a photo of what I am doing. The main view contains a scrollview (blue area) which contains a uiview (green area). My issue is that when I rotate the green area, some of it gets clipped off. So I need to rotate it then resize it, but unsure how to resize it properly. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcuTI.jpg)

Comment: first animate a scale and then rotate when you have finished reset the scale

Comment: How do I know what the scaling size is

Comment: start with 0.9 and try adjusting the value until you find the one you like

Comment: The views in the green are dynamic and vary in size. Sorry I forgot to mention that. So I dont think that would work well